# Objective-C - Is it possible to drag an item and lock it on a certain position?

Tags: drag-and-drop, position

How can I drag an image or button, then when the image is on a specific spot, i.e. (x = 240 y = 240) it will stay there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume iOS as I'm more familiar with it than with OS X.

To make a view draggable, detect a touch dragging it using the following three methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

The trick is that you should store the touch's location in the view's superview, then in the 2nd method, update the position of the view itself accordingly. When you detect that the view's center or origin reached a certain point (don't check it using ==, it doesn't work well for floating-point numbers, use some small epsilon to detect whether the view is inside a desired **area**), you can set a boolean flag on the view, then check that boolean flag in the touchesMoved method and not update the view's location anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the response.... but where will I place the code??? i'm really sorry Im really new to xcode.... and if you can provide a sample code will REALLY REALLY be a life saver....

Comment: @imkakoy you need to subclass UIView and put all the code in that subclass. Sorry but I'm a bit of in hurry so I can't write a complete draggable UIView for you now (anyways it's not what SO is for), but I can provide you with two method names to grep for in the official Apple docs: [NSSet anyObject] and [UIView locationInView:].